# What does "representative sample engine" mean for an overhaul extension?

Tags: aircraft-maintenance, terminology

If the PT6 turbo prop engine is required for an extension for overhauling due to operational reasons, the manual has to be searched if the extension is feasible for the company. The company states that for the overhaul extension to be carried out a "representative sample engine" is required. What does a representative sample engine mean? Does it specify a part of the engine to be sent to check if the extension is feasible?